# Should the tag Telegram-Messenger be removed?

Tags: discussion

There currently is a tag called [Telegram-Messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/telegram-messenger) with very few questions for it.

Telegram, like WhatsApp is a web app that has a desktop client for it. Although I can see how one would want to ask a question regarding the desktop app, most questions will really be about telegram itself, and not a specific feature that is exclusive to the desktop app. Also the telegram app for smartphones will be mistaken by it.

I honestly think this tag is confusing and questions should be migrated to Web Apps.Stack Exchange.

What do other people think? Should the tag [Telegram-Messenger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/telegram-messenger) be allowed or not?

Comment: There are 36 questions, most of which look on topic after skimming that link. I would say keep the tag but edit the tag wiki to make clear it's about using the telegram client on a computer and not about the mobile app or the web client.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather rename it to Telegram-Desktop. I'd expect this to eliminate the confusion.